# Django React CSRF Issues

Tags: django, reactjs, django-cors-headers

Building my first app using Django as back end and React as front end.

Locally, I have both running on port 8000 and 3000 respectively.

I have a short snippet of code I found online to help me test whether or not my CSRF and CORS policies are set correctly:

```
const API_HOST = 'http://localhost:8000';

let _csrfToken = null;

async function getCsrfToken() {
  if (_csrfToken === null) {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_HOST}/csrf/`, {
      credentials: 'include',
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    _csrfToken = data.csrfToken;
  }
  return _csrfToken;
}

async function testRequest(method) {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_HOST}/ping/`, {
    method: method,
    headers: (
      method === 'POST'
        ? {'X-CSRFToken': await getCsrfToken()}
        : {}
    ),
    credentials: 'include',
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data.result;
}


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      testGet: 'KO',
      testPost: 'KO',
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      testGet: await testRequest('GET'),
      testPost: await testRequest('POST'),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Test GET request: {this.state.testGet}</p>
        <p>Test POST request: {this.state.testPost}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT to clarify: Remote GET request passes, only POST fails**

When I run this code locally, I get the correct response which is, the "KO" gets changed to "OK" when the responses come back valid.

This only works from my machine. If I try to access it from any other machine in my network, I get the following error:

403 Forbidden

Django's debug reason is that "CSRF cookie not set".

However, in the console, I can see the headers are indeed sending the X-CSRFToken.

I have a "live" version of my backend that I've also tried to tap into with same results as locally.

I only get a successful test if I try it from my own computer, where both dev servers sit.

Django settings:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['localhost:3000', 'My_Public_Ip:3000']
```

I suspect my issue is somewhere in that whitelist but I'm at a loss at this point to find what it is.

If someone could help me understand what's happening, if they don't have an answer, that might trigger an "aha" moment.

Comment: I don't know how do you exactly sending cors headers - list is not allowed actually so you should always return exact domain. But it would generate normal response and error in console with info about cors, not 403. I would guess you are doing something wrong with retrieving that csrf token, try to debug this part.

Comment: I'm not following exactly. The headers are sent with this: 
 headers: (
      method === 'POST'
        ? {'X-CSRFToken': await getCsrfToken()}
        : {}
    ),
    credentials: 'include',
  });

I can confirm that the token is being sent 
(at least to my understanding it is), I'll take a screenshot and add it to the OP.

Comment: The screenshot shows send a header called `X-CSRFToken` but not the cookie itself. Can you confirm that when everything works fine locally a cookie is sent also? Maybe you can also add a screenshot of the request header for a working request?

Comment: @BernhardVallant I have updated with screens, trying your answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides @tgdn's recommendation of getting the token from the cookie i would also recommend checking your `SameSite` policy settings for the [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-samesite)- and [Session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite)- Cookies, as setting it to `Strict` or `Lax` will also probhibit the cookies being sent in cross-origin requests (which could result in losing your session/being logged out etc...).

Comment: Okay, maybe it's the time of night or the flu I'm fighting but I can't seem to comprehend the correct place to set this. From what the docs say, if I'm understanding correctly, the default setting is the least restrictive?

Comment: No the least restrictive would be disabling it with `None`. Maybe try that and see if it solves your issues... `Lax` still doesnt allow the sending of cookies in cross-origin requests https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite ... And accoriding to your new screenshot `SameSite=Lax` seems to get applied.

Comment: I haven't fixed it yet, but your last comment finally made it all click for me. It's working locally because both of my dev servers are running off of localhost, just a different port, so the SameSite never kicks in but as soon as I try remotely it does. Will report back as soon as I find where to set this!

Comment: Quick update, I forgot to mention that my GET requests pass, even remotely, it's the POST requests that fail, will update OP.

Comment: Seems to fit as the `SameSite` policy should block CSRF-prove requests like `POST`.

Comment: I have been able to verify that my cookie is being set by Django with the "lax" attribute. Now before I go sorting that out, would I still have this issue if I had users who were logged in? I'm wondering if that's why it's upset, because no one is logged in right now during this testing phase. Although now I'm wondering how I'd get them signed up if they can't POST.

Comment: Does it work if setting it to `None` for session and csrf cookie? Logging in relies on the session cookie to be set properly so this doesnt solve it.

Comment: Marked as the answer.I still need to find the fix but this is the cause of my OP problem.

Comment: If you want to keep the cookies set to `Lax` there's no real solution for cross-origin requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187683/discussion-between-david-morin-and-bernhard-vallant).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried getting the CSRF token from the actual cookie rather than making a request to the server?
Because really what you are doing now is getting the CSRF token every time you are trying to fetch anything.

Try something like the following in your JavaScript:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

async function testRequest(method) {
    const headers = {};
    const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken'); // or the value from settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME
    if (csrftoken) {
        headers['X-CSRFTOKEN'] = csrftoken;
    }
    const response = await fetch(`${API_HOST}/ping/`, {
        method,
        headers,
        credentials: 'include',
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.result;
}
```

Comment: I have managed to get this to work locally, similar to the code I already had but when I try remotely I get the same issues as before, Django denies the request and the reason given is that the CSRF cookie is not set. My browser does have a cookie set in the cookies section. I will next have to see if @Bernhard Vallant's suggestion is where my error lies.